# Wiring TFT Display to Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: gpio, display, pitft

I just need some help wiring [this](http://www.dx.com/p/3-2-inch-tft-ips-480-x-320-262k-color-full-angle-lcd-module-for-arduino-mega2560-blue-black-369199#.VR0rV_nF_-o) TFT LCD for the Raspberry Pi. I want to use it as a console/x display. I've Googled and read through everything I could find on SE, but I can't apply what I find to my LCD. A format similar to this would be great: DB1 - GPIO18

I'm sure this is easy to do, I've just been working a lot and during the little time I have to work on my own projects I'm too tired to accomplish anything, and I would really appreciate any help you guys can give me. Sorry if this question is answered elsewhere, I'm sure I've read it and just couldn't understand.

[Here](http://ozzmaker.com/2013/05/23/raspberry-pi-with-a-3-2-tft-with-touch-control/) is one of the many links I've read that I can't seem to grasp at the moment.